# Error while starting jetty server in Geonode Installation

Tags: geonode

I am trying to install Geonode developer install from:

**http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/tutorials/devel/devel_env/**
after following the instructions given in documentation and start the server by **paver start** I am getting the following error:

```
2016-11-19 05:58:10.809:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/geoserver,file:/home/farook/geonode/geoserver/geoserver/},../geoserver
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:504)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:625)
Caused by: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1514)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1864)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:367)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:504)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:625)
 2016-11-19 05:58:10.817:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened /home/farook/geonode/geoserver/jetty.log
  2016-11-19 05:58:10.845:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
  java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:504)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:625)
2016-11-19 05:58:10.851:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@37bc2b18: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:504)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:625)
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:463)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:288)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:504)
at org.mortbay.jetty.runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:625)
Usage: java [-DDEBUG] [-Djetty.home=dir] -jar jetty-runner.jar [--help|--version] [ server opts] [[ context opts] context ...] 
Server Options:
--version                          - display version and exit
--log file                         - request log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
--out file                         - info/warn/debug log filename (with optional 'yyyy_mm_dd' wildcard
--port n                           - port to listen on (default 8080)
--stop-port n                      - port to listen for stop command
--stop-key n                       - security string for stop command (required if --stop-port is present)
--jar file                         - a jar to be added to the classloader
--jdbc classname properties jndiname - classname of XADataSource or driver; properties string; name to register in jndi
--lib dir                          - a directory of jars to be added to the classloader
--classes dir                      - a directory of classes to be added to the classloader
--txFile                           - override properties file for Atomikos
--stats [unsecure|realm.properties] - enable stats gathering servlet context
--config file                      - a jetty xml config file to use instead of command line options
Context Options:
--path /path       - context path (default /)
context            - WAR file, web app dir or context.xml file
```

Comment: What is your java version? Check with `java -version`

Comment: Something else is using port 8080

Comment: How to start the paver in someother port?

Comment: @user30184: My java version is 1.7.0_121

Comment: Real error is perhaps here `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/geoserver/GeoserverInitStartupListener : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`, but I do  not know what is having the wrong version.